# grep: How to exclude directories?

Tags: grep, macos

When using grep with wildcards as in

```
grep -in github */*
```

for each directory `grep` shows lots of messages like

```
grep: dir1/dir2: Is a directory
```

How to suppress these messages?

Using the flag `--exclude-dir` does't work to my surprise.

I'm using `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` on MacOS.

Comment: I were able to reproduce the behavior in CentOS/RHEL 7.x via `grep --exclude-dir="dir*" -in "test" */*`. It seems to be come form the last `*` as specifying a file i.e. `*/*.sh` let the error did not come up. Of course, it doesnt answer why bash or the command is behaving this way.

Comment: @U880D thank you, but too much to write and how to support recursive -R with that solution?

Comment: maybe `grep -rin github .`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-d skip` will make grep skip directories:

> grep -in -d skip github */*

According to [this MaxOS man page](https://ss64.com/osx/grep.html) that option should work for MacOS grep.  If it turns out that this doesn't work with the MacOS grep you can install then [Homebrew MacOS package manager](https://brew.sh/) and then use Homebrew to install the [GNU version of grep](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/grep), since GNU grep supports `-d skip` (though in that case you'll have to make the directory containing GNU grep the first in your `PATH` environmental variable).

Comment: perfect. works. thank you.

Comment: Right, I were able to reproduce the behavior in CentOS/RHEL 7.x via `grep --directories skip -in "test" */*` and which was working as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` to **find** files and `grep` to **g/re/p** within the files:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec grep -in github {} \;
```

There are big clues to each tools purpose in their names :-).